# Using PostgreSQL, how can I count the amount of individuals that opened a message in the previous 30 days from the Monday of each week?

Tags: postgresql, business-intelligence, window-functions

**Scenario:**
I have a table, events_table, that consists of records that are inserted by a webhook based on messages I send to my users:

*"column_name" (type)*
- "time_stamp" (timestamp with time zone)
- "username" (varchar)
- "delivered" (int)
- "action" (int)

**Sample Data:**

```
|    time_stamp   | username | delivered | action |
|:----------------|:---------|:----------|:-------|
|1349733421.460000|  user1   |     1     |  null  |
|1549345346.460000|  user3   |     1     |   1    |
|1524544421.460000|  user1   |     1     |   1    |
|1345444421.570000|  user7   |     1     |  null  |
|1756756761.980000|  user9   |     1     |  null  |
|1234343421.460000|  user171 |     1     |   1    |
|1843455621.460000|  user5   |     1     |   1    |
|      ...        |   ...    |   ...     |  ...   |
```

The "delivered" column is null by default and 1 when *delivered*. The "action" column is null by default and is 1 when *opened*.

**Problem:**
Using PostgreSQL, how can I count the amount of individuals that opened an email in the previous 30 days from the Monday of each week?

**Ideal query results:**

```
|      date       |   count   |
|:----------------|:----------|
|   02/24/2020    | 1,234,123 |
|   02/17/2020    |  234,123  |
|   02/10/2020    | 1,234,123 |
|   02/03/2020    |12,341,213 |
|      ...        |    ...    |
```

**My attempt:**
This is the extent of what I've tried which gives me count of the previous week:

```
SELECT
  date_trunc('week', to_timestamp("time_stamp")) as date,
  count("username") as count,
  lag(count(1), 1) over (order by "date") as "count_previous_week"
FROM events_table
WHERE "delivered" = 1
     and "action" = 1
GROUP BY 1 order by 1 desc
```

Comment: "**Ideal query results**" -- Knowing these is pretty useless without knowing the input. So [edit] the question and add sample data that corresponds to that expected result as `INSERT INTO` statements.

Comment: something like ``` SELECT yourdate, count(DISTINCT CASE WHEN yourdate BETWEEN yourdate-INTERVAL '30 day' AND yourdate THEN username END)
WHERE to_char(yourdate,'dy')='mon'
AND "action"=1
GROUP BY 1```

Comment: Your requirement "30 days from the Monday of each week" is ambiguous. Today is 2020-03-06, a Friday. Then 30 days prior is 2020-02-05, a Wednesday> So do you want effect does "Monday" have on that. Is it retrieve from the week starting 2020-02-03 or 2020-02-10, both Monday, or from 2020-02-05 ignoring the fact that it is not Monday. Or start from Monday 2020-03-02 (Monday starting week today is in), with the same relative issue as before.  All of which are valid interpretations of "30 days from the Monday of each week". The problem being number of days does not correspond to days of week.

Comment: @Belayer If I run a query like I've provided under "My attempt:" at this exact moment, todays date (2020-03-06) wouldn't apply to any result from the query. My table, events_table, does not include records from the future, and therefore the first date returned by that query would be 2020-03-02. So, if I ran the query under "My attempt:" during the day on 2020-03-09 (next Monday), 2020-03-09 would return as a result, with a count. Moreover, I'm not concerned about what day of the week a Monday - 30 days is. I am only concerned about the result. Does this help?

Comment: That's fine. My point was you need to be careful with how requirements are stated as they can be indentured several ways. And that may lead to erroneous results.

Comment: @Belayer do you have any suggestions on how I might improve my question or description? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my attempt at writing this query.

First I get the lowest and highest dates from the data set. I add 7 days on to the highest date to make sure I include data up to today.

I then run `generate_series` against these 2 values set with an interval of 7 days to give me every single monday between the 2 points (we can't rely on just mondays within your data set in case we have an empty week)

Then, I simply subquery and aggregate the data  based on our `generate_series` output.

```
select
    __weeks.week_begins,
    (
        select
            count(distinct "username")
        from
            events_table
        where
            to_timestamp("time_stamp")::date between week_begins - '30 days'::interval and week_begins
            and "delivered" = 1
            and "action" = 1
    )
from
    (
        select
            generate_series(_.min_date, _.max_date, '7 days'::interval)::date as week_begins
        from
            (
                select
                    min(date_trunc('week', to_timestamp("time_stamp"))::date) as min_date
                    max(date_trunc('week', to_timestamp("time_stamp"))::date) as max_date
                from
                    events_table
                where
                    "delivered" = 1
                    and "action" = 1
            ) as _
    ) as __weeks
order by
    __weeks.week_begins
```

I'm not particularly keen on this query because the query planner visits the same table twice, but I can't think of another way to structure it.

Comment: I'll check it out!

Comment: at first glance it looks like it works! ty for your contribution! Now, to check by hand...